# Advanced Custom Fields Repeater image not showing in for loop

Tags: wordpress, url, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I added a ACF repeater field called "Eye Condition Type" with the variable "ect"

[image: 1]

above are the values of the repeater fields: text, text area, image, url

when trying to display all the fields, all of them work except image. This is what I am trying to fix.

[image: 2]

above are sample inputs of the repeater and below is the code to show them on a page:

[image: 3]

```
$ect = get_field('ect');

<?php
    if( $ect ) { ?>
    <div class="page-w-70-ecu"><div class="row"><?php
        foreach( $ect as $e  ) {
            echo'<div class="col-md-4">'; ?>
                     
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $e['ect_image']['url'] ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $e['ect_image']['alt'] ); ?>" />

         <?php echo'<h2 class="foreach-h">'.$e['ect_header'].'</h2>
                    <p>'.$e['ect_desc'].'</p>

                 <a href="'.$e['ect_learn_more'].'" class="learn-more">
                    <p>Learn More</p>
                    <img src="" alt="arrow">
                 </a>
                 </div>';
        }
        ?></div></div><?php
    }
?>
```

as you can see from the image, my for each code outputs everything else except the image. For context, non repeater image fields work if I add the same code in them:

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( $e['ect_image']['url'] ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $e['ect_image']['alt'] ); ?>" />
```

what is the fix to show the image url in the src?

I also tried to output the `['ect_image']` in a `<p>` and it only outputs "Array"

Hope I provided enough information, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your ACF field name is `ect_img` and you are trying to output `ect_image`. Using `ect_img` in your output should solve the issue.